# Windows 7 remains powered on when restarting

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, reset

I'm running windows 7 x64 on an MSI P67A-GD53 motherboard, in an Antec P280 Super Midi Towercase with a Corsair 650w PSU.

I've just installed a second instance of windows 7 x64 on a separate disk (this is to keep my games separate from my work OS).

The problem is that it appears now that I cannot restart from either instance of Windows 7. The shut down command, and sleep commands work as expected. When I try to restart, the shutdown happens but the system never reboots. Everything remains powered on, until I hold down the power button to force the power off.

Ithink (but am not 100% sure) this has only started since I installed the second OS, and am assuming this has something to do with the motherboard needing to know which OS to run up again? Some other forums I've read suggest that the PSU has a major role in restart and could be at fault.

Changing the boot order of the disks in the BIOS does not change anything.

Any suggestions greatfully recieved!

**Update: I now have a reproduceable issue:**

I think the secondary OS install may have been a red herring. It was when windows tried to reboot during the install that I noticed the issue.

After playing around with installing drivers, and rebooting many many times, I have found that it is the OC genie setting on the MSI motherboard that seems to trigger the problem. This makes sense as I only started using the OC genie feature a couple of weeks ago, and probably hadn't used restart in that time.

However... simply turning off OC genie does not make the issue go away. I have to turn off OC genie, shutdown, start enter bios, go to the "Save and Exit" menu > "Restore Defaults" > yes to "Load optimized defaults", which will reset to clear the problem.

Now when the PC boots into windows, I can restart as normal (and from the OS on either HDD).

I only know how to control the issue, and don't still know the root cause. I'd like to be able to use the OC genie function if anyone can suggest a why I'm seeing this problem. Could it be that I'm drawing too much power when using OC feature?

Comment: It would be greatly helpful if you knew that this happened before installing the OS. If it didn't, then it's not the PSU.

Comment: No bios splash screen after restart?

Comment: @ekaj - I agree. I hadn't noticed it before this point, but then I don't reboot that often.

Comment: @Moab - That's just it, there is no automatic restart. I can power the machine back on again, and I get the splash screen as normal.

Comment: Just trying to get a feel for exactly at what point in the restart cycle it is failing.